# How to make correct logout?

Tags: php, slim, logout

I do logout by `post` method and redirect response to main page, but to get main page's html I need to use `get` method.

How should I do correct redirect from `post` to `get`?
Or is there any more appropriate methods to logout?

I use Slim v3 framework for that and it doesn't allow to redirect from one method to another.

```
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->renderer->render($response, 'index.phtml');
});

$app->post('/logout', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $this->model->logout($response)->withRedirect("/", 308);
});
```

As I know, doing logout via `POST` method and get html page via `GET` is best practise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use response code *302* and it will automatically use *GET*.

*308* preserves the request method. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/308

A non-cached redirect like *302 Found* is also more advisable in your case, rather than a permanent one like *301*/*308*.

Comment: Yes, as advised a permanent redirect may bypass your route - due to browser caching.

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: @Progrock i cant upvote you, cos just have 7 reputation :( but thank you